# arulesSequences cspade function: "Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection"

Tags: r, arules

One day I tried to execute my routine cspade sequences mining in R and it suddenly failed with error and some very strange print to console. Here is the example code:

```
library(arulesSequences)
data(zaki)
cspade(zaki, parameter=list(support=0.5))
```

It throws very long output (even with option control=list(verbose=F)) followed by an error:

```
CONF 4 9 2.7 2.5
MINSUPPORT 2 4
MINMAX 1 4
1 SUPP 4
2 SUPP 4
4 SUPP 2
6 SUPP 4
numfreq 4 :  0 SUMSUP SUMDIFF = 0 0
EXTRARYSZ 2465792
OPENED C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp279Wy5\cspade2cd4751e5905.idx
OFF 9 38
Wrote Offt 0.00099802
BOUNDS 1 5
WROTE INVERT 0.000998974
Total elapsed time 0.00299406
MINSUPPORT 2 out of 4 sequences
1 -- 4 4 
2 -- 4 4 
4 -- 2 2 
6 -- 4 4 
1 6 -- 3 3 
2 6 -- 4 4 
4 -> 6 -- 2 2 
4 -> 2 6 -- 2 2 
1 2 6 -- 3 3 
1 2 -- 3 3 
4 -> 2 -- 2 2 
2 -> 1 -- 2 2 
4 -> 1 -- 2 2 
6 -> 1 -- 2 2 
4 -> 6 -> 1 -- 2 2 
2 6 -> 1 -- 2 2 
4 -> 2 6 -> 1 -- 2 2 
4 -> 2 -> 1 -- 2 2 
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file             
'C:\Users\Dawid\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp279Wy5\cspade2cd4751e5905.out': No 
such file or directory
```

It looks like it is printing the mined rules to the console (which has never happened before). And it ends with error so I can't write the rules into a variable. Looks like some problem with writing temporary files maybe?

My configuration:

- R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
- Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
- Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Packages:

- arulesSequences_0.2-19
- arules_1.6-1

(arulesSequences have new version but on the latest version arulesSequences_0.2-20 it fails in the same way)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to use the R console, not Rstudio.

Well, it should work fine then. I see that more people have the same problem. I have tried reinstalling Rstudio together with reinstalling packages and using older Rstudio version but it didn't work.

Hope it helps but I would be grateful for a full answer. Thanks!